# How can I call a javascript function which is outside my angular App without importing it

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular app, by clicking on a button, I want to call a javascript function which is outside my angular app.

Also I think I can't really import the javascript into my angular app.

I'm trying to extend a platform actually, it has a `main.ec78f7c1aff5e487c247.bundle.js` script on a page which contains a method `doSomething()` that I want to use in my angular app which is imported on the same place. 
(But I don't want, if this main is updated to update my import path anytime too, because the `ec78f7c1aff5e487c247` would change then or?)

When I type `window.location = 'javascript:doSomething("stringParamItNeeds")'` in the browser console, the exact method that I need is called. 
But I don't know how to do this inside my angular app. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it on the global scope? If yes, you should be able to call it by `window.functionName()` or simply `functionName()`

Comment: First of all - it's completely unclear what's going on, explain please. Where the function is actually, what means outside app and other details too. Second, `window.location = 'javascript:doSomething("stringParamItNeeds")'` - in this line you call `doSomething` function; if this is what you want to do and the function defined as global in your app too, so you can call this function at any moment in your angular.Third, `I can't really import the javascript` - just do it bro, \*shia_labeouf.gif\*

Comment: As I understand it there are three files, one which imports two scripts: on with the doSomething Method (lets call it doSomethingApp) and second my angularapp - the doSomething method is known on the script which imports both (where I use the console input on), but is not known on my angular app, I think Gopal Yadav's answer is close to what I need

Comment: the main problem is that I have limited control on the script which has the doSomething(), Im extending a plattform, where I cant modify the source code so easy, I have a website, where I can add a script which is imported into the main.script thats all

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the function which you want to call is available to your program (your Angular app). One of the ways is to register the function in global scope i.e. window object and then you will be able to access it in your program (Angular app).

For example -
"`function demo () {  }`" is the one you want to call in your Angular app which is available in script file main.hash1.js

Step 1:
Register the function demo on the window object, `window.demo = function() { ... };`

Step 2:
In your angular app, you can simply call `window.demo()` or simply `demo()` function.

Step 3:
If you are using static type checking tools like Lint/Sonar etc, it may show error in your application that demo object is not available on window. You need to declare or mock the demo property on window object in you angular app code to solve the issue.

Comment: a question to step 1: this needs to be done in the javascript (outside my angular app, where the doSomething Method lies or?). I'm a little bit confused actually because still new to angular, so maybe I'm doning syntactically something wrong, but when use: window.addRecord : Function = function() { }; in my typescript component then I get the error: ';' expected

Comment: Yes step 1, indicated to make changes in the main.ec78f7c1aff5e487c247.bundle.js file where you have your function definition which you want to call in your Angular app.

Comment: ok in the javascript (doSomethingApp) it is already registered on the window object, but when I try to call it in angular (step 2), i get "property doSomething()" doesnt exist on window (because its not imported) how can I tell angular to ignore that or somehow that the window object HAS the property at this moment

Comment: Yes, this will give an error in your dev environment - step 3 in my comment is for this action only. Can you please tell what exactly are you trying to do? It seems you are loading an angular app inside another angular app. 

Is your Angular application includes the main.ec78f7c1aff5e487c247.bundle.js file as an external script file in index.html?

Please clarify then I will be able to provide you with a more accurate solution on this. If possible please share a small working stackblitz demo for your problem.

Comment: Ok I try to explain it better, its really complex sorry: Im trying to extend a plattform (html website, which seems to have a javascript or even an angular app already included, only thing that I know is, when I use in the console window.doSomething(), the correct method is called. This plattform allows me to use an onload hook,where I can paste in the options of the plattform a little script, which I use to bring my angular app into the plattform ui. I guess the javascript where doSomething() is in the window obj, is the one who imports my angular app (how can I find this out via browser?)

Comment: Okay let me break it down, you have a website which loads some scripts (main.ec78f7c1aff5e487c247.bundle.js is one of them). You are hooking up an Angular application using onload provided by your platform. Is that correct? If yes, then may be the issue you are facing is dev specific issue, you may not see this when you bundle up all the things and run it in a real environment where your website loads main.ec78f7c1aff5e447.bundle.js script and then your angular app code. To solve the dev env issue you can mock it (see next comment) and make sure it should not get executed in real environment.

Comment: To mock you can use a script with below content and load it in dev environment and exclude it in higher envs.

```
(function () {
    window.demo = function () {
        console.log('demo called');
})();

```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197216/discussion-between-gopal-yadav-and-alloisxp).